# Porque me cambia la hora al insertar?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Hola pues estoy manejando una gráfica donde se visualiza la fecha y la hora y claro los parámetros, pero al momento de insertar la hora y la fecha la hora se adelanta 5 horas.

Para insertar tomo la hora y la fecha del equipo actual y la inserto en un campo Timestamp, y en la base de datos se captura correctamente la hora y la fecha que es, pero al mostrarlo en la gráfica me muestra 5 horas demás. Les dejo la muestra de la gráfica y abajito la hr real al insertar en a bd.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿como estás formateando la fecha y hora para mostrarlas? puede que se estén convirtiendo a hora local, aplicando una diferencia horaria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede que sea el problema con la zona horaria, prueba cambiarlo con:

[`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Ejemplo funcionando: [Ver Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6c6a43c0b6c58f7b5702cdb6b3b5425e52ed964a)

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$d = new DateTime('now');
echo 'Zona America: ' . $d->format('d-m-Y H:i');

echo PHP_EOL;

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');

$d = new DateTime('now');
echo 'Zona Europa: ' . $d->format('d-m-Y H:i');

// Resultado
// Zona America: 19-07-2017 14:13
// Zona Europa: 19-07-2017 23:13
```